# Why wordpress AStudio themerex's theme ask sometimes for local FTP connection parameters?

Tags: wordpress, parameters, ftp, local

Each time more then 2 images are uploaded to Media, or sometimes when a page is in execution a Form asking for FTP login parameters is displayed like an error...

Comment: After some research.

I changed the folder rights to Read/Write everyone ...  - It did not fix it -
Then using MAMP the php version was changed from 7.0 to 7.1
It did not resolve the issue...
æ
So, the problem is still open.

It seems some kind of problem related with the theme. 
(https://themerex.net/?s=AStudio)

Comment: more information, like error logs will help us to give right answers

Comment: Hi Samvel ! I will try to check the error logs... and text you soon. Now I can send you the error message : Informations de connexion

Pour lancer la requête demandée, WordPress a besoin d’accéder à votre serveur web. Veuillez saisir votre identifiant FTP pour continuer. Si vous ne vous souvenez pas de votre identifiant, vous devriez contacter votre hébergeur.

Nom de l’hôte :  
Identifiant FTP  
Mot de passe FTP   Le mot de passe ne sera pas stocké sur le serveur.
Type de connexion FTP FTPS (SSL)

Comment: And this is the php error log : [17-Jan-2018 22:05:58 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function submit_button() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rockartz/wp-admin/includes/file.php:1767
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rockartz/wp-content/plugins/trx_addons/includes/plugin.files.php(172): request_filesystem_credentials('http://192.168....', 'ftpext', false, false, Array)

Comment: #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rockartz/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): trx_addons_init_filesystem('')
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rockartz/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rockartz/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rockartz/wp-settings.php(434): do_action('after_setup_the...')
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rockartz/wp-config.php(89): require_once('/Applications/M...')

Comment: #6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rockartz/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/Applications/M...')
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rockartz/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php(22): require_once('/Applications/M...')
#8 {main}
  thro in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rockartz/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 1767

Comment: Sorry. I am not yelling at all... its all that capslock was on...

Comment: I will try to change the title

Answer (score 1):

After some research and any answer from the theme company's support.
The next patch was applied and all seems to work well.

File : wp-content/plugins/trx_adons/includes/plugins.files.php
Line 163 commented
//add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'trx_addons_init_filesystem', 0);

File: wp-content/themes/astudio/includes/utils.php
Line 726 commented
//add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'astudio_init_filesystem', 0);

If the issue returns i will keep you informed!